# Problem with people and hats after lunch

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve interesting probability problem which I found in the book "50 Mathematical Ideas You Really Need to Know" by Tony Crilly:

*A group of people go to lunch and afterwards pick up their hats at random. What is the probability that no one gets their own hat?"*

So he claimed that *It can be shown that this probability is $1/e$ (about $37\%$) so that the probability of at least one person getting their own hat is $1 – 1/e$ $(63\%$)*

I was thinking about asymptotic cases where $n \to \infty$. The probabilities of "*no one gets their own hat*" and "*at least one person getting their own hat*" should be $0$ and $1$ respectively, right? So why it is $1/e$ and $1-1/e$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement

Comment: I don't see why your limits of $0$ and $1$ should hold, intuitively.

Comment: The tag (eulers-constant) is intended to be used with number $\gamma$, known as Euler's constant or Euler-Mascheroni constant, rather than $e$, often called Euler's number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [n people & n hats: probability that at least 1 person has his own hat](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/922473/n-people-n-hats-probability-that-at-least-1-person-has-his-own-hat)

Answer (score 2):

For exact answer you can see here: [At a party $n$ people toss their hats into a pile in a closet.$\dots$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/876126/at-a-party-n-people-toss-their-hats-into-a-pile-in-a-closet-dots) and here: [Question on the 'Hat check' problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627913/question-on-the-hat-check-problem).

For $n\to\infty$ you can approximate the distribution with the Binomial distribution. Note that the probability that $k$th man will pick his own hat is $\frac{n-1}{n}\frac{n-2}{n-1}\cdots\frac{n-k+1}{n-k}\frac{1}{n-k+1}=\frac{1}{n} $ wich holds for each $k=1,...,n$, where $n$ is the number of people/hats. Hence, for $n\to \infty$ you can "neglect" the intrinsic dependency between the trials and state that whether the $k$th man picks the right hat is Bernoulli r.v. with $1/n$; $X_k \sim Ber(1/n)$. Hence, the total number of successes follows the Binomial distribution with $n$ and $1/n$, $\sum_{k=1}^nX_k\sim Bin(n, 1/n)$.  Consequently,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P\left(\sum_{k=1}^nX_k=0\right)= \lim_{n\to\infty}\binom{n}{0}\frac{1}{n^0}\left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n =\lim_{n\to\infty} \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)^n = e^{-1}\,.
$$

Answer (score 1):

How [Brian Tung](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/224454/brian-tung) pointed this is [Derangement problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) with solution:

$P = 1 - !n / n! $

where $!n$ - subfactorial of $n$; $n!$ - factorial of $n$.