# Interesting probability with hats

Tags: probability

There are N people in a room, each wearing a different hat. They all take their hats off,
put them together and then each randomly picks one up. What is the probability of no person
getting their own hat back (denote this event by A)? What does this probability become as
N → ∞ ?
Can somebody give me some ideas, please?

Comment: What have you tried? What techniques are available to you? Probably the most systematic and universal approach is the method of inclusion-exclusion.

Comment: You can refer to this post: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589915/problem-with-people-and-hats-after-lunch?rq=1

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#Counting_derangements).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with people and hats after lunch](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1589915/problem-with-people-and-hats-after-lunch)

Comment: The word to google: derangement.